# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data

Tags: multithreading, sockets, http, tcp, webserver

I am writing **ThreadPooled Web Server**. But I found a very big problem, and my head is banging in trying to solve this problem. At the end I am unable to solve this. The problem is very strange.

When I am running Web Server, sometimes it shows 
`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.`
and sometimes it runs fine. But I didn't understand why this all happening.

Please help me to overcome from this strange problem.

**EDIT NO. 1**

When I run my HTTP web server on Google crome, it gives more 324 error than in firefox. Why ?

Comment: @All I found that this problem mainly comes in Chrome browser. Can anybody tell me , is this a browser related issue, or code missing problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are writing locally.
Are you working around Apache MPM threadpool? Or Its something else?

In General:
 1. [localhost case] Check your .htaccess file if you are running server locally [Using your own custom server.or if your server build around Apache MPM ]. If you are not using Apache  and its a purely a custom build from start.Your server is closing the connecting without returning any value. 
 2. [Intranet Case]  Check your router, .htaccess
 3. [Web Server Case] Check your router, .htaccess 
 4. Please read the below link.
 5. [For Every body else] Simply refresh the page.

Below Link have detailed help.

[How To Fix Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)](http://www.slideshare.net/JessicaNokk/how-to-fix-error-324-neterremptyresponse)
[Apache MPM threadpool](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/threadpool.html)